# Communicate directives/controller and scopes

Tags: javascript, angularjs

First of all say that what I'm writing is translated by google translate hope all well understood.
My problem is that in the example different scope are made, with the next and previous buttons I change a variable and according to the number where it is you have to put in bold the number from the list (do not understand why in plunker the Next button it works). Does anyone see the problem ?. Also I would like dijeseis me if the solution to the problem I have raised right or wrong or how to improve it, thanks. a greeting

The plunker -> `https://plnkr.co/edit/IDisg3wCYoeCbslJO3wn?p=preview`

```
angular
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem that you have it´s that you are sharing your "controller" on the index.html `<body ng-controller="controller">` and as well on the steps directive.js `controller: 'controller'`

That´s not a good practice, you should have separate controllers. And you can structure your code to be something like

 1. controller (The top level)
 2. steps (directive with a controller that have # steps, next, previous, isActive) and then this directive uses two directives, described below.
 3. previous (directive where you inject the previous function)
 4. next (directive where you inject the next function)

Comment: You mind making a test code? I'm starting with this and still be good practice to do things

Comment: Look at the next example there is a "controller" that uses $scope and the steps directive use the stepsCtrl and use controllerAs (it's a best practice that you might want to learn more about) https://plnkr.co/edit/KV4utux3KdXmKsKtBZSE?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

So I think what you want is the number to be **bold** when you move through the list using the Previous/Next buttons.

You seem to have a lot of files to do just this.

You can consider having an array of items [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] and using `ng-repeat` to render them.

You can have a `$scope.currently_active` variable that keeps track of what is currently selected.  Your next/prev buttons would change this value

When the `$scope.currently_active` value matches (equals) the value in your ng-repeat based directive, then you simply have the css style change to be bold.

If you need an example code, please ask.  Typically people are happy to provide working examples (such as plunkr)

Comment: consider which is the best way to do ?. Can you teach me a code? I'm stuck with this